# Editing/Updating Graphs in Haskell

Tags: haskell, graph, simulation

I'm using a Data.Graph Graph to model a simulation in Haskell. The simulation is limited to a 2D grid which my graph models. A node at each point on the grid below will contain a Maybe Molecule type so there could be a molecule present or just Nothing.

```
1  - 2  - 3  
|    |    |  
4  - 5  - 6  
|    |    |  
7  - 8 -  9
```

I have set up this representation but when it comes to updating the position of a molecule I feel I'm going the long way around the issue. What I've done so far is stripped all the nodes into a list of nodes. I've written a function to swap the two items in this list of nodes. But now when I come to zip everything back together I come into problems because to generate a new graph I need a list of vertices which I obtain easily from the vertices Graph function. But I also need to zip that with the list of vertices the edge touches. Unfortunately Data.Graph's edges Graph function returns a list of tuples of type Edge which isn't immediately helpful for generating a graph as far as I can see, although I could write a function to derive the list vertices which have edges to a vertex. Doing so seems to be enough work for me to wonder am I missing the point is there a Graph function out there which does just take a graph and return a graph with an updated node?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

FGL has this great "context" mechanism that lets you pattern match on a graph query. You can imagine this as tugging on a chosen vertex so that it sits to the side of the rest of the graph. This lets you look at how that that vertex is connected to the rest of the graph.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-}
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Arrow
import Data.Graph.Inductive

-- Example graph from SO question.
graph :: Gr (Maybe Int) ()
graph = mkGraph (map (id&&&Just) [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
                (map (\(x,y) -> (x,y,())) $
                     concatMap gridNeighbors [1..9])
  where gridNeighbors n = map (n,) 
                        . filter ((&&) <$> valid <*> not . boundary n) 
                        $ [n-3,n-1,n+1,n+3]
        valid x = x > 0 && x < 10
        boundary n x = case n `rem` 3 of
                         0 -> x == n + 1
                         1 -> x == n - 1
                         _ -> False

-- Swap the labels of nodes 4 and 7
swapTest g = case match 4 g of
               (Just c4, g') -> case match 7 g' of
                                  (Just c7, g'') -> setLabel c4 (lab' c7) & 
                                                    (setLabel c7 (lab' c4) &
                                                     g'')
                                  _ -> error "No node 7!"
               _ -> error "No node 4!"
  where setLabel :: Context a b -> a -> Context a b
        setLabel (inEdges, n, _, outEdges) l = (inEdges, n, l, outEdges)
```

You can try running `swapTest graph` to see that the labels for nodes 4 and 7 in your diagram are swapped.

Answer (score 4):

Is there a particular reason that you are using graphs here? It seems to me that the set of edges is pretty much fixed and that your grids only vary in the positions of the molecules.

Why don't you just use arrays or some other data structure that allows you to focus on the molecules and their positions? For example:

```
import Data.Array

data Molecule = H2O | CO2 | NH3

type Grid = Array (Int, Int) (Maybe Molecule)

-- creates an empty grid                                                        
grid :: Int -> Int -> Grid
grid m n = array ((0, 0), (m - 1, n - 1)) assocs
  where
    assocs = [((i, j), Nothing) | i <- [0 .. m - 1], j <- [0 .. n - 1]]

-- swap the molecules at the specified indices                                  
swap :: (Int, Int) -> (Int, Int) -> Grid -> Grid
swap (i, j) (u, v) grid =
  grid // [((i, j), grid ! (u, v)), ((u, v), grid ! (i, j))]

-- etc.
```

(If you have good reasons to use graphs, I am of course completely out of line here, in which case I apologise...)

Comment: if I use graphs I can see if adjacent nodes are occupied by other molecules for collision detection checks.

Comment: @mikeyP But you can do that with arrays as well, can't you?

Comment: You're right, underneath a Graph is an array. But with a graph I'll be able to remove nodes on the graph, areas that the molecules can't pass through. I can't see a neat way to do that  with Arrays.